# Drop event fires twice on inherited panel

Tags: c#

I´ve created my own control inherited from the panel control with OnDrop method for handling Drop event. Unfortunately, the event is fired twice. 
I don´t know why.

here my code

```
public partial class Panel_my : Panel
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StartDateProperty =
           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StartDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(Panel_my), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EndDateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EndDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(Panel_my), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MaxValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxDateProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("MaxDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(Panel_my), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MaxValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinDateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MinDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(Panel_my), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MaxValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));


    public static DateTime GetStartDate(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DateTime)obj.GetValue(StartDateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetStartDate(DependencyObject obj, DateTime value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(StartDateProperty, value);
    }

    public static DateTime GetEndDate(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DateTime)obj.GetValue(EndDateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEndDate(DependencyObject obj, DateTime value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EndDateProperty, value);
    }

    public DateTime MaxDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(MaxDateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxDateProperty, value); }
    }

    public DateTime MinDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(MinDateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinDateProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);
        }

        return new Size(0, 0);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double range = (MaxDate - MinDate).Ticks;
        double pixelsPerTick = finalSize.Width / range;

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            ArrangeChild(child, MinDate, pixelsPerTick, finalSize.Height);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    private void ArrangeChild(UIElement child, DateTime minDate, double pixelsPerTick, double elementHeight)
    {
        DateTime childStartDate = GetStartDate(child);
        DateTime childEndDate = GetEndDate(child);
        TimeSpan childDuration = childEndDate - childStartDate;

        double offset = (childStartDate - minDate).Ticks * pixelsPerTick;
        double width = childDuration.Ticks * pixelsPerTick;

        child.Arrange(new Rect(offset, 0, width, elementHeight));
    }

    protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {

        }
        e.Handled = true;

    }

}
```

When I place a button on the panel and move it in the drag & drop process and drop it on that panel, the drop event is fired twice.

What can I do to have only one drop event?

Comment: Look at the designer.cs file for the registering of the events ('+=').  You must have the panel and the inherit panel registered.

Comment: I don´t register any handler with +=. In the inherit panel there ist the OnDrop method. This method is being called twice because there is somehow twice the drag event.

Comment: All event MUST be registered!!!  Look at the designer.cs file!!!

Comment: I went through all my .designer.cs and others  .cs file. There is no registration with +=

Comment: You need a += for an event to work.  They can be either in the designer or regular cs file.  So you cannot be getting to the event.  You can put a break point into the event to verity if you are getting into the event.  You can also look at the call stack to see how you got into the event.

Comment: here is my code:

Comment: sorry, lets try better:

Answer (score 1):

I got it. The problem is that the button fires event MouseMove not only when the mouse is moving but even when the left button is pressed without moving the mouse. 
I changed the method OnMouseMove and than it works!

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && this.IsPressed == false)
    {
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, this.Content, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

Thank you, **@jdweng** very much for help and direction!!!